# How to get date 'start_ts' in query for last 30 days- oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT trunc(start_ts) ,STATUS 
    FROM table1
)
PIVOT (
    COUNT(STATUS) FOR STATUS in ('ERROR' error, 'COMPLETED' Completed)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `start_ts > sysdate-30` will restrict the start_ts to last 30 days.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT trunc(start_ts) ,STATUS 
    FROM table1 where start_ts > sysdate-30
)
PIVOT (
    COUNT(STATUS) FOR STATUS in ('ERROR' error, 'COMPLETED' Completed)
);
```

Comment: please add some text to describe answer - Review

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram - The same goes for the question, no?